# bash outputs star and quotation mark incorrectly

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal

so I have this bash function:

```
function xyz(){
  echo $@
}
```

now when I run

```
xyz whaat  "loool * hahhaa"
```

instead of echoing `whaat "loool * hahhaa"`

it insteads echoes:

```
whaat loool all default hahhaa
```

First of all the quotation marks got stripped off.
Secondly the * got replaced by "all default" . This is because the current directory has 2 folders called "all" and "default" hence it think * refers to all directory in the current directory

Is there a way to modify my function so that the output becomes the intended `whaat "loool * hahhaa"` accordingly (including the quotation marks and *)

I tried doing `${@}` `"$@"` and `"${@}"` to no avail

Comment: If you want  to keep the quotation mark, you can enclose them in single quotation marks. `xyz whaat  '"loool * hahhaa"'` Should work with both `"$@"` and `"${@}"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quotation marks are really gone, so don't be expecting anything to put them back. Bash removed them as part of parsing the command line (search for "quote removal" in `man bash`).

However, either `echo "$@"` or `echo "${@}"` will avoid the glob expansion (replacing `*` with the directory listing).

You practically never want `$@`. Best to get in the habit of writing `"$@"`.

If you want to see a quoted version of the arguments, you can a bash-extension to printf:

```
xyz() {
  printf "%q " "$@"
  printf "\n"
}
```

Comment: Note that the printf trick won't necessarily quote them the same way they were originally -- it'll produce an equivalent quotation/escape sequence. So `xyz whaat "loool * hahhaa"`, `xyz whaat 'loool * hahhaa'`, and `xyz whaat  loool\ \*\ hahhaa` all produce exactly the same output. And they have to, because they are all equivalent. `xyz` function receives *exactly* the same arguments from all three commands.